# Show div of related checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to show a div when the page loads with a checked radio button.

I have this code which will show a number or input field, depending on the radio clicked:

HTML:

```
<p><input type="radio" name="service" value="auto" checked> Automatic</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="service" value="menu"> Menual</p>

<div id="auto" value="1" class="details">
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
<div id="menu" value="2" class="details">
  <input name="bizid" type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter number"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.details").hide();
    $("input[name$='service']").click(function() {

      // used for auto service
      Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      var x = document.getElementById("demo")
      x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

      // show div of checked radio on click
      var test = $(this).val();
      $("div.details").hide();
      $("#" + test).show();
    });
});
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2cp9w5g/)

I want to make this work as needed, so when the page loads it will show the checked div right away..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

separately call the click function on window load .And change the selector with test `var test = $("input[name$='service']:checked").val();` instead of `$(this).val()`

for my suggestion use `change` event instead of `click`  for radio buttons

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.details").hide();
check();
  $("input[name$='service']").change(check);
  
  function check() {

    // used for auto service
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var x = document.getElementById("demo")
    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    // show div of checked radio on click
    var test = $("input[name$='service']:checked").val();
    $("div.details").hide();
    $("#" + test).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="radio" name="service" value="auto" checked> Automatic</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="service" value="menu"> Menual</p>

<div id="auto" value="1" class="details">
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
<div id="menu" value="2" class="details">
  <input name="bizid" type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter number" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to manually `trigger()` a click event on the first radio on load of the DOM.

Also note that you can improve the logic by using jQuery's `text()` method, and removing the `Math.floor` whose result you don't use. Try this:

```js
$("input[name$='service']").click(function() {
  $('#demo').text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
  $("div.details").hide();
  $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
}).first().trigger('click');
```

```css
div.details { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="radio" name="service" value="auto" checked> Automatic</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="service" value="menu"> Menual</p>

<div id="auto" value="1" class="details">
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
<div id="menu" value="2" class="details">
  <input name="bizid" type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter number" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.details").hide();
set();
    $("input[name$='service']").click(function() {

  // used for auto service
  setno();

  // show div of checked radio on click
  var test = $(this).val();
  $("div.details").hide();
  $("#" + test).show();


    });
});

function setno(){
  Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var x = document.getElementById("demo")
  x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}

function set(){
setno();
if( $('#chk-auto').attr('checked')){
  $("#auto").show();
 }
}
```

working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nczzkozo/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showDiv = function() {
    // used for auto service
    Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var x = document.getElementById("demo")
    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var test = $("input[name$='service']:checked").val();
    $("div.details").hide();
    alert(test)
    $("#" + test).show();
};
$("input[name$='service']").click(function() {
  showDiv();
});
showDiv();
});
```